# How to write json file in Unity3d using MiniJSON?

Tags: android, json, unity-game-engine

Recently using MiniJSON in Unity3d, I can just read the json file from WWW class(from a webserver or local storage). Now I'm just wondering how to write the string to a json file, then save it on Application.persistentDataPath or send the json file to server? Json.Serialize() just converts data into a string but does not write the json to a file and that's what I really want.

Does anyone have some solid experience on writing json just like Json. Writer in LitJson or alternatively generate a .json file with php?

-Android/iOS Platform

Answer (score -1):

Traditionally you would want to send the JSON via an HTTP request, not a whole file. Here's an example HTTP request in Unity3D: [Unity GET/POST Wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951489/unity-get-post-wrapper)

In the end you'll be sending something that looks like:

```
http://www.YourSite.com/YourFile.php?someJson={"Your":"Json"}
```

I would advise you read up on the HTTP Protocol before attempting to implement it, there is plenty of information on the web about it. But long story short, two common methods of the protocol are GET and POST. Both Unity3D and PHP support this protocol.

In PHP, you'll do something like the following to get the variable when the page is called form Unity and write the data to a file:

```
// Get JSON from HTTP Request.
$jsonData = $_GET["someJson"];

// Write JSON to file.
file_put_contents("data/my-data.json", $jsonData);
```

To write data to a file in Unity3D:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:/YourPath");

sw.Write(YourJSON);

sw.Close();
```

Hope this helps.